# Thread with lot of autoreleased objectIs is it mandatory to use autorelease pool on this scenario if yes/no why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool

Consider we are implementing our own thread with lot of autoreleased object. Is it mandatory to use autorelease pool on this scenario if yes/no why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mandatory to have an autorelease pool on [any thread that you create](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW16), because [Cocoa internals expect](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) there to be one in place and you will leak memory if it isn't there.

> Cocoa always expects there to be an autorelease pool available. If a pool is not available, autoreleased objects do not get released and your application leaks memory. If you send an autorelease message when a pool is not available, Cocoa logs a suitable error message.

---

> Applications that link in Objective-C frameworks typically must create at least one autorelease pool in each of their threads.

Comment: Well, it's not _quite_ mandatory. It is perfectly defined what will happen: objects leak, and messages get logged. While that isn't usually what you want, that doesn't mean it couldn't possibly be what you want…

Answer (score 3):

It is mandatory even with a single autoreleased object, because otherwise it will leak.